# Date and Time Extraction from an XML File: Python

Tags: python

[XML Tree Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QIQB.jpg)
[XML Tree Structure (cont'd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3NJh.jpg)

Code below is written in python

```
import os

import lxml.etree as ET

import re

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\Wadi\Desktop')

tree = ET.parse('XMLData.xml')

pathology_case_retrieval_report = tree.getroot()
```

The 0th child of the root element (Pathology_case_retrieval_report) is the report_info tag. This tag contains no information about any specific case. Individual cases start with the CASE at index 1 of the root element.

```
for case in pathology_case_retrieval_report[1:]:
```

All CASE have 3 children tags: caseAccesion, caseDetails, and caseReport.

```
    for caseAccesion_caseDetails_caseReport in case:
        for reportSection in caseAccesion_caseDetails_caseReport:
            for title_text in reportSection:
                if title_text.tag == 'TITLE':
                    if title_text.text == 'Gross Description':
                        x = 'Gross Description'+ ':' +title_text.getnext().text
                        print(x)
```

We are only looking for TITLE tags inside of the REPORT_SECTION. Of the TITLE tags inside of the REPORT_SECTION we only care about those which have 'Gross Description' in between them. Of the TITLE tags inside of the REPORT_SECTION which have 'Gross Description' in between them we are only interested the textual information of its immediate (and only sibling).

Here is a sample of what the output look like:

```
Gross Description: TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT.

Specimen collected: d-d-dd/dd:dd. Specimen placed in formalin: dd:dd.

Gross Description: TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT Specimen collected: dd:dd. Specimen placed in formalin: dd:dd.

Gross Description: TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT.

Specimen collected: d-d-dd/dddd. Specimen placed in formalin: dddd/d-d-dd.

TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT

Specimen collected: d-d-dd/dddd. Specimen placed in formalin: dddd/d-d-dd.
```

I've written regex to to capture the the string,'Specimen collected: d-d-dd/dddd. Specimen placed in formalin: dddd/d-d-dd'. However, I eventually need to capture just the date and time (convert to integers). How would I go about doing this?

Also, when I "print(x)" I would like the data to appear like this:

```
1) Gross Description: The specimen,...
Specimen collected: dd:dd. Specimen placed in formalin: dd:dd.
2) Gross Description: Specimen A, ...
Specimen collected: d-d-dd/dddd. Specimen placed in formalin: dddd/d-d-dd.
Specimen B, ...
Specimen collected: d-d-dd/dddd. Specimen placed in formalin: dddd/d-d-dd.
```

Essentially, I would like each gross description to be numbered so I can keep track of it. How would I go about numbering them?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Collect your result data to list of tuples, add counter variable to loop, and when adding data to tuple, also add there counter value. Then, when you'll print out result (list), then print out each element, which could be:
- counter value (order number);
- gross description;
- specimen info, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve been trying to find a way to collect my results inside of a list? Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you

Comment: grossDescriptionslist = []

for case in pathology_case_retrieval_report[1:]:
    for caseAccesion_caseDetails_caseReport in case:
        for reportSection in caseAccesion_caseDetails_caseReport:
            for title_text in reportSection:
                if (title_text.tag == 'TITLE' and title_text.text == 'Gross Description'):
                    grossDescriptions = 'Gross Description'+ ':' +title_text.getnext().text
                    grossDescriptionslist.append(grossDescriptions)